# Optimal solution for creating sorted sub-arrays from array in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having a list of events like this

```
  [
  {
    name: "E1",
    category: "C1",
    start: 1588335000000,
  },
  {
    name: "E2",
    category: "C2",
    start: 1588335101000,
  },
  {
    name: "E3",
    category: "C1",
    start: 1588335040000,
  },
  {
    name: "E4",
    category: "C2",
    start: 1588335101005,
  },
  {
    name: "E5",
    category: "C1",
    start: 1588335102000,
  },
  {
    name: "E6",
    category: "C1",
    start: 1588335222000,
  },
  {
    name: "E7",
    category: "C2",
    start: 1588335282000,
  },
];
```

My task is to create sub array based on following criteria

1. Group events based on category
2. Group only those events in which consecutive start time has less than 1 minute
   difference, otherwise further subgroup them as separate sub array
3. All sub array should be sorted by start time
4. Overall list should be sorted by first event in that category.

Based on above criteria desire output should look like this

```
[
  [
    { "name": "E1", "category": "C1", "start": 1588335000000 },
    { "name": "E3", "category": "C1", "start": 1588335040000 }
  ],
  [
    { "name": "E2", "category": "C2", "start": 1588335101000 },
    { "name": "E4", "category": "C2", "start": 1588335101005 }
  ],
  [{ "name": "E5", "category": "C1", "start": 1588335102000 }],
  [{ "name": "E6", "category": "C1", "start": 1588335222000 }],
  [{ "name": "E7", "category": "C2", "start": 1588335282000 }]
]
```

I am trying following solution

```
 const getEventSubArrays = (events) => {
  events.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.start - b.start || a.category.localeCompare(b.category);
  });

  const finalRes = events.reduce(
    ([running, prev], curr) => {
      if (
        !prev ||
        prev.category !== curr.category ||
        curr.start - prev.start < 60000
      ) {
        running.push([]);
      }
      running[running.length - 1].push(curr);
      return [running, curr];
    },
    [[]]
  );
  console.debug(finalRes[0]);
  return finalRes[0];
};
```

But it is not returning correct results, also I am not willing to use any third party dependecies.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: "It's not working" (== _"it is not returning correct results"_) is a useless problem description. Add the current output and/or convert the separate parts of your question into an executable snippet so we can work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce` for this problem is probably suboptimal because it doesn't give you much control and requires some hacks for more complicated problems like your's.
I suggest using a good old for loop which gives you much more control. The solution I came up with probably isn't the most efficient, but it works as desired.

The algorithm works as follows:

1. Sort the events with the primary sorting criterion being the category and the secondary sorting criterion being the start value.
2. Create a group containing the first event.
3. Iterate over the sorted events starting with the second event. If the current event has the same category as the previous event and the difference in the starting values is less than 60000 (i.e. a minute assuming milliseconds) than add the current event to the last group created. Otherwise create a new group and add the current event to this group.
4. Sort the groups based on the name of the first event in each group.

```js
const events = [{name:"E1",category:"C1",start:1588335000000,},{name:"E2",category:"C2",start:1588335101000,},{name:"E3",category:"C1",start:1588335040000,},{name:"E4",category:"C2",start:1588335101005,},{name:"E5",category:"C1",start:1588335102000,},{name:"E6",category:"C1",start:1588335222000,},{name:"E7",category:"C2",start:1588335282000,}];


// sort events
// primary sorting criterion: category
// secondary sorting criterion: start
events.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.category.localeCompare(b.category) || a.start - b.start;
});


const groups = [
    [events[0]]
];

// group objects having the same category and a difference in start being less than 60000
for (let i = 1; i < events.length; i++) {
    const prev = events[i - 1];
    const curr = events[i];
  
    if(prev.category === curr.category && curr.start - prev.start < 60000) {
      groups[groups.length - 1].push(curr);
    }
    else {
      groups.push([curr]);
    }
}

// sort groups by name of a group's first element
groups.sort((a, b) => a[0].name.localeCompare(b[0].name));

console.log(groups);
```

Comment: _"Using reduce for this problem is probably suboptimal because it doesn't give you much control and requires some hacks for more complicated problems like your's. I suggest using a good old for loop which gives you much more control."_ - `.reduce()` is a `for` loop (or `.forEach()`) with return value o.O

Comment: @Andreas `reduce` is an abstraction of a for loop with a different interface. What I meant is that this very interface of `reduce` makes the implementation of the solution in this case more complicated and harder to maintain. A for loop on the other hand has a much more basic interface allowing for easier customizations which are simpler to read.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the subgrouping and focusing first in sorting by: time, category and name (if I understood correctly ) you can use this:

```js
var arr = [ { name: "E1", category: "C1", start: 1588335000000, }, { name: "E2", category: "C2", start: 1588335101000, }, { name: "E3", category: "C1", start: 1588335040000, }, { name: "E4", category: "C2", start: 1588335101005, }, { name: "E5", category: "C1", start: 1588335102000, }, { name: "E6", category: "C1", start: 1588335222000, }, { name: "E7", category: "C2", start: 1588335282000, }, ];

function compareName(a, b) {
  return a.name < b.name ? -1 : a.name == b.name ? 0 : 1;
}

function compareTime(a, b) {
  return a.start < b.start
    ? -1
    : a.start == b.start
    ? compareCategory(a, b)
    : 1;
}

function compareCategory(a, b) {
  return a.category < b.category
    ? -1
    : a.category == b.category
    ? compareName(a, b)
    : 1;
}

console.log(arr.sort(compareTime));
```

Having the sort part done I think is easy to subgroup the collection with `reduce` ro similar.